Random Forest Test split
I have trained Random forest model using June dataset to predict status_value of an employee and  using 0.3 split for test_size. I am including code snippets as the code it self works well without any errors
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
rf.fit(X_resampled,y_resampled)
y_pred = rf.predict(X_test)

when I use trained RF model to predict the status_value without splitting July dataset it still only predicts for 30% of the employees and not the full dataset.
ml_cols = ['age','months tenure','salary_deviation','review_rating','term reason enc','color_rating','satisfaction score','ytd commission','Sales Activities','DurationOfSalesCall','MileageOfSalesCall','Referrals','Admits']
ml_df_pred =merged_df_pred[ml_cols]
X_pred = ml_df_pred[ml_cols]
y_fcst = merged_df_pred['status_value']
y_pred = rf.predict(X_pred)

How do I go about ensuring that it doesn't split July data and predicts for all 180 employees listed in July dataset?

Did you check that you actually have the 180 employees in X_pred?

Your code does not really make sense. What are X_resampled and X_pred? What are the columns in X? What is the purpose of ml_df_pred?

To ensure that the trained Random Forest model predicts the status_value for all 180 employees in the July dataset without splitting it, you need to make sure that the input data (X_pred) has the same format and columns as the data used for training (X_resampled).
Also, check the missing values and handle its and If you have a normalize data  during training, apply the same normalization.

Thank You Francisco- I ascertained that X_pred indeed has 180 rows and at each preprocessing step to ensure data is not inadvertently filtered out. ALso, pre processing code for June and July is identical. I am pulling data out of the same file for both months so I am pretty certain that format, column names and data treatments are same. I re-trained model as rf2 on full Jun data without splitting and now it predicts for 100% of July data so   that worked but feels like it's a shortcut

Hey, I am glad that all works out for you. Just remember that random forest are great to predicts with the trained data but kinda for new data, So check with new data the real percentage of accuracy. Always is good try with different models and check the weight of the variable in our results.
Good luck! and give me an "up" if my answer was useful :)!
